# access to server's localhost:8080/project_name from outside

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-ec2, localhost, mamp

I am using MAMP on my server (ec2's server) and the url (localhost:8080/project_name) works fine locally on the server but when I am trying to access the path (server_public_ip:8080/project_name) from outside  I get the error "This site can’t be reached"

I tried to open port 8080 on firewall but it's not working.
is anyone have solution for this??

Comment: You need to add the DNS entry for your domain ( eg. example.com) , which will be bind to your global ip , and allow the inbound outbound traffic from aws dashboard to outsiders .

Comment: Change security group settings follow aws doc

Comment: I didn't get the answer.. how I can do that? do you have a guide or something?

Comment: Open port `8080` in the security group assigned to the EC2 instance.